# Drawing an arrow on top of an image - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to draw an arrow on top of an image in MATLAB, between two pixels: [x0,y0] and [x1,y1].

I tried to use annotation function. The problem is that the function takes as an input x,y values which represent coordinates on the figure, instead of on the image itself.

Does anyone knows how can I draw an arrow between two pixels in an image?

**Example**

```
 imshow(imread('peppers.png'));hold on;
```

I would like to generate a blue arrow from pixel (1,1) to pixel(200,200), so it should look something like this (only in blue instead of black):

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: See the `coordinate2normalized` helper function from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33852712/add-arrows-in-phase-space-portrait-matlab/33899451#33899451) or [one](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54254-coord2norm) or [more](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10656-data-space-to-figure-units-conversion) of the [many options on MATLAB's File Exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?search_submit=fileexchange&query=normalize+annotation&term=normalize+annotation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could simply use the [quiver](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html)-function:

```
figure;
imshow(imread('peppers.png'));hold on;
quiver(0,0,200,200,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! is there a way to make the size of the head bigger?
when the arrow is short (for example, from (0,0) to (5,5)) the head is too small to be seen

Comment: @Ibezito `quiver(0,0,200,200,0,'MaxHeadSize',10)`

Comment: You have a lot of options [here](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiverseries-properties.html).