# Plot lines that end with a square bracket

Tags: matlab, plot, customization, matlab-figure, linestyle

**My goal:** plot a horizontal line with a square bracket (`---]`) end to it.

I usually plot horizontal lines with

```
line([0,1],[2,2],'linestyle',':')
```

I can add usual markers at the end by

```
plot([0,1],[2,2],'o')
```

but not square bracket.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for that but what is your question?
add square brackets to which command and what argument location?????

Comment: @AboLregal The question is perfectly clear, he wants to add a square bracket *in a plot* as a marker. Also please dial down on the usage of question marks, one is more than enough to show that you have a question.

Comment: A possible, but probably computationally more heavy than necessary, can be found [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36070755/5211833): overlay and image of a square bracket at the end of the line.

Comment: @Adriaan thanks, but I'm still hopefull for something easier. If all else fail, then this will be the solution...

Comment: it can't except the color
because matlab deal with name and value as strings

Comment: rgb in markercolor

Comment: @AboLregal first off, please use the `@username` syntax when replying to people, so that they actually see your comment. As to the contents: there's no mention of colour here, so what does that have to do with the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a terrible hack that kinda achieves what you want:

```
XVALS = [0,1; 0,2; 0,3].';
YVALS = [3 3; 2,2; 1,1].';
INVIZ_OFFSET = 0.04;
figure(); 
% Step 1: Plot squares:
plot(XVALS(2,:), YVALS(2,:),'bs');
% Step 2: Plot invisible squares:
hold on;
plot(XVALS(2,:)-INVIZ_OFFSET, YVALS(2,:),'ws','MarkerFaceColor','w');
% Step 3: Plot lines
plot(XVALS, YVALS,':b');

% Play with limits:
axis image; xlim([0,5]); ylim([0,4]);
```

Result:

[image]

The idea is that a "bracket" marker can be obtained using an obscured square marker. Obviously this isn't suitable for all plots, but I think you can work from here...

Answer (score 3):

I think your simplest option would be the `text` command:

```
l = line([0,1],[2,2],'linestyle',':');
text(l.XData(end),l.YData(end),']','VerticalAlignment','middle',...
    'FontSize',12,'FontWeight','bold','Color',l.Color)
```

You can go further and add a rotation:

```
x = 0:0.1:0.5*pi;
p = plot(x,cos(x)+1.5,'--r');
text(p.XData(end),p.YData(end),']','VerticalAlignment','middle',...
    'Rotation',atand(diff(p.YData(end-1:end))/diff(p.XData(end-1:end))),...
    'FontSize',12,'FontWeight','bold','Color',p.Color)
```

The rotation is not perfect, but it's a good start. Here is the result:

[image: bracket end]

---

**EDIT:**

For a pre-2014b version of Matlab you will need to use the `get` function:

```
l = line([0,1],[2,2],'linestyle',':');
x = get(l,'XData');
y = get(l,'YData');
text(x(end),y(end),']','VerticalAlignment','middle',...
      'FontSize',12,'FontWeight','bold','Color',l.Color)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, when I type the `l=line(...` command I get just a `double` for `l`, which doesn't have any fields or a structure to it. Any thoughts on why's that?

Comment: @AmirSagiv that's strange. Do you get the line plotted? maybe you have a variable called `line`? Try to run this in a fresh session of Matlab. Alternatively, replace `line` with `plot`, as in the second example above (you can keep the same input).

Comment: Still the same with `plot` in a fresh session. Is this a relatively new feature of Matlab? I'm running a 2013a.

Comment: @AmirSagiv Well, now it's clear. You cannot use the `.` notation for graphic handles before 2014b. I have edited my answer for previous versions.